# Testing Protocols With Protocol Extensions

Tags: swift, protocols, xctest

I have a protocol and multiple implementations of said protocol. It seems like it would be a good pattern to create a test protocol with a protocol extension to then test all of the implementations. Something like:

```
protocol CommonTests {
    var testObject: SomeProtocol!

    func testA()
    func testB()
}

extension CommonTests {
    func testA() { ... }
    func testB() { ... }
}

class SomeClassATests: XCTestCase, CommonTests {
    var testObject: SomeProtocol!
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        testObject = SomeClassA()
    }
}

class SomeClassBTests: XCTestCase, CommonTests {
    var testObject: SomeProtocol!
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        testObject = SomeClassB()
    }
}
```

But Xcode 7.1 doesn't seem to accept this. The code doesn't seem to run and the tests do not show up in the Test navigator.

Does anyone have a good way to test multiple implementations of a protocol without rewriting a ton of code?

**Edit** I added the test functions explicitly to the `CommonTests` protocol definition, to no avail.

Comment: Did you try to have implementation inside protocol ? without any extensions? 
for more information please read "Mixins and Traits in Swift 2.0"

Comment: Protocols cannot have implementations, only definitions for functions / properties.

Comment: please read more about swift 2.0. It can have implementation

Comment: Protocols in Swift 2 can have implementations provided by Protocol Extensions, as show above.

The issue is that Xcode and XCTest do not properly recognize them.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's possible to put `setup` in the protocol? I tried this but my tests aren't running it...